# many user interact with WSO2-DAS at the same time

Tags: session, apache-spark, stream, wso2-das

I have an event stream witch store data in table for batch processing.

if many users send data at the same time, the event stream store data in one only table.
my question is:  can i tell my event stream to store the data of each users in a separate table or can i send param to batch script sparkQL?

Comment: Do you specify user information as an attribute in the stream?

Comment: many thanks for your comment. I don't know how to specify user information as an attribute in the stream.